# Using Dynamic ClassName for Casting in java?

Tags: java, casting

i have a requirement where i have to use dynamic class names to Cast variables.

For example:

I have below classes :

```
Oranges
Mangoes
Papayas
```

Now i want to fetch `bookingamountnumbers` of this fruits dynamically. 
Also my all classes extends one base class `FruitsBase`

I want to do something like this:
Calling Function:

```
if(Oranges)
{
myFile.buildData({Oranges});
}
else if(Mangoes)
{
myFile.buildData({Mangoes});
}


 public void buildData(confirmFruitsBooking bookingFruits,className<?> nameOfClass) throws Exception
 {
 FruitsBase fruitConfirm = bookingFruits.getAmountConfirmation();
 Map buildMap = new HashMap();
 buildMap.put(Constant.BOOKING_NUMBER, (DynamicClassNamelike(Oranges,Mangoes,Papayas))fruitConfirm.getBookingAmountNo());
 }
```

Please guide. I already Reflection API

Comment: I'm quite sure that you don't have a *requirement* for using dynamic casts. You have just chosen this way to attempt to solve your problem. Describe your problem instead. It would be very bad design to try to do what you're doing here, and there's most likely a simpler, cleaner option.

Comment: Instead of doing this, it sounds like `getBookingAmountNo` should be in `FruitsBase` (or an interface that all of the fruits to which it's relevant implement). Then you work with variables/parameters declared as `FruitsBase` (or the interface).

Comment: Don't read up on Reflection.  It's almost never the correct answer, and frankly I think it's beyond your current grasp of the language.  Instead, read up on Polymorphism.